# Запись данных в csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

парсю данные:

```
bb_strings = re.findall(r'var model = ({.*})', ad)
bp = {}
if bb_strings:
bp = json.loads(bb_strings[0])
    for bl in bp['AVAILABLE_SIZES']:
    footlocker.append(('razmer', bl))
```

На выходе я получаю данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что бы на выходе получалось?:

Чтобы размеры и картинки не дублировались и были не строках, а столбцах?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте привести *полный*, но *минимальный* пример кода, который проблему показывает. Поправьте заголовок, чтобы он отражал действительную проблему в вопросе как вы её понимаете. Явно опишите ввод, желаемый вывод и что вместо этого получается. [mcve]

Comment: @jfs отредактировал вопрос

Comment: не вижу где `df` пополняется. Отсупа перед `footlocker.append()` возможно не хватает.

Comment: df = DataFrame(columns=('заголовки', 'размеры','img' )), добовление footloker в df(footlocker.append(('images', ld.split('/')[-1]))) и запись в csv df.to_csv('foto.csv', index=False, sep=';')

Comment: @jfs если я добовляю отступ, то у меня делаются дублежи тоесть данные добовляютс rows, а не columns

Comment: У вас тогда все значения  ld кроме последнего игнорируются. Метод append для списка всегда None возвращает. Попробуйте всё-таки выполнить рекомендации из моего самого первого комментария: создайте самодостаточный пример (используйте искусственный фиксированный ввод, уберите всё что не является совершенно необходимым, чтобы ошибку показать)

Comment: @jfs обновил вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56043/discussion-between-fermeg-and-jfs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 razmer = 0
 bb_strings = re.findall(r'var model = ({.*})', ad)
 bp = {}
 if bb_strings:
 bp = json.loads(bb_strings[0])
     for bl in bp['AVAILABLE_SIZES']:
     razmer +=1
     footlocker.append(('razmer%s' %razmer, bl))
```